# Not getting params in header

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm not getting params to my header in main(homeStack) screen.

When I change createBottomTabNavigator with Home: {screen: Home}, not with Home: {screen: homeStack} than parameters are transferred to my header successfully in that screen. I don't know why this happens. PLease help me to get that user data to my header in Home screen.

Also, I want to have a different header in each of the tabs and I want to display data to header via params, which I put in login as:
navigation.navigate('Home', { user: user });

My app.js code:

```
const homeStack = createStackNavigator({
    screen1: { 
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
                  },
                  headerTintColor: '#fff',
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                  },
     },
    },
},{ initialRouteName: 'screen1'});

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
        Login: { 
          screen: Login,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          }
         },
        Main: {
            screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
                Home: { screen: homeStack },
                Profile: { screen: Settings },
            }, {
              initialRouteName:'Home',



            })
        }
    },{ 
      initialRouteName: 'Login',

    });


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Routes />
    );
  }
}
```

Code in screen home where is header:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
    console.log(navigationOptions);
    console.log(navigation);
    // Notice the logs ^
    // sometimes we call with the default navigationOptions and other times
    // we call this with the previous navigationOptions that were returned from
    // this very function
    /*return {
      title: navigation.getParam('user', 'A Nested Details Screen'),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: navigationOptions.headerTintColor,
      },
      headerTintColor: navigationOptions.headerStyle.backgroundColor,
      headerTitle: navigation.state.params.user.name,

    }; */
    return {
      headerTitle: navigation.state.params.user.name,
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did the issue got fixed?

Comment: I did in another way...